# MPMoviePlayerController “Loading Movie from server

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

its problem when i play the video it shows black screen and playing audio without the video and can't do any thing but close app.
here is my code

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 


 NSString *movieURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.aliakbar84.com/test/%d.mp4",indexPath.row];

 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:movieURL]];
[moviePlayer play];
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieplayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieurl];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieplayer1];
```

Comment: Why exactly are you initializing both, `MPMoviePlayerController` AND `MPMoviePlayerViewController`? That should not be done. Remove the initializing of `MPMoviePlayerController`!

Comment: thaaaanx so much its working perfictly

Comment: I will repeat this hint to prevent an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly are you initializing both, `MPMoviePlayerController` **and** `MPMoviePlayerViewController`?

That should not be done. Remove the initializing of `MPMoviePlayerController`!